# Succinct way to describe "clocking in" page on a web app

Tags: word-choice, expressions

A Swedish colleague has asked for my suggestion for web app page titles. The task has left me and a fellow native speaker stumped... The answers should apply to British and American English.

1. A page for users to "clock in" and "clock out". We're even unsure whether or not there is a better term for indicating presence at work than this.
2. A page to view all clocked times. My initial thought was "timesheet"?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, I don't recall a proper name for those machines except 'clocking-in machine'. Everywhere I worked that had one, you were simply told to 'clock-in/out' at the 'clocking-in machine'

Answer (score 2):

One *punches in / clocks in* and *punches out / clocks out* using a *time card* inserted into a *time clock*, *clocking-in machine* or *time recorder*. The resulting data might be recorded in/on a *timesheet* or *log*.

Today, one might record similar information in a computer-based system by *logging in* and *logging out*.

Comment: I hadn't even thought of logging in/out. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

"Sign In" and "Sign Out" is also used when the clock metaphor isn't as accurate.